# jQuery .prop('outerHTML') without styles (get only tagName, classNames and ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way in jQuery that we can use .prop('outerHTML') only to get the Element and without getting any style? Because if the Element have inner styles, the 'proped' will include not only the tagName, classNames and ID, but will include the styles as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard the `style` attribute entirely, you could easily write a simple jQuery extension which discards the attribute using [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). For example:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
        return $(this).clone().removeAttr('style').wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#outer').val( $('#myDiv').outerHTML() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div" id="myDiv" style="width: 100px;height:100px"></div>
<textarea id="outer"></textarea>
```

Comment: There's a full working demo included in the snippet.. Just copy the extension into your JS file, and then call it as I've shown.